# cy.contains() cannot be passed an empty string

Tags: javascript, html, select, cypress

I'm testing my django server front-end with cypress. I should test the case where user selects empty string from options list. The code

```
//Next try to remove frequency    
cy.get('select').eq(5).find('option').contains('').then((selectOption) => {  
        cy.get('select').eq(5).select(selectOption.text());
});
```

led to error message:

```
cy.contains() cannot be passed an empty string
```

although the empty string belongs to my choices:

html:

```
<select id="id_update_freq" calss ="form-control" name="update_freq"
    <option value="">""</option> 
    <option value="vk">Viikkotilasto</option>  
    <option value="kk">Kuukausitilasto</option> 
    <option value="nv">Kolmannesvuositilasto</option>
    <option value="kv">Puolivuositilasto</option>
    <option value="pv">Vuositilasto</option>
</select>
```

How can I test the case ?

Comment: "DOM elements can contain more than the desired text and still match." ([docs](DOM elements can contain more than the desired text and still match.)) So if you said `.contains('o')`, all but the empty option would match. If `contains` allowed an empty string, every element would match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`select()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select):

> Select an `<option>` within a `<select>`.

```js
describe('78120822', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    cy.get('#id_update_freq').select('');
    cy.get('#id_update_freq').should('have.value', '');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

One problem you have is the HTML has no `<option>` with empty string. The first option is the one you try to select, but it has two quotes in the string, so it's not ***technically*** empty.

So in your test this will pass

```js
cy.get('select').find('option').contains('""')
```

But after fixing the typo,

```html
<select id="id_update_freq" calss ="form-control" name="update_freq">

  <option value=""></option>     <-- this is how an empty option looks
  ...

</select>
```

you can then select the empty option by using RegExp in the `.contains()` command

```js
cy.get('select')
  .find('option')
  .contains(/^$/)                     // regexp for empty string
  .should($emptyOption => {
    expect($emptyOption.index()).to.eq(0)      // passes
  })
```

Of course, `cy.select()` works too :).